Can "sneak into the closet" mean something not stopping being open?
Web search for "in the closet" finds links about being non-open about one's sexual orientation.
From a book I'm reading:

many, or perhaps even all, theoretical physicists long for that
blissful moment right after death when the Creator reveals how the
universe is put together. (Surely, even some of the self-proclaimed
atheists whom I know might occasionally sneak into the closet late at
night to wish for the answer to this ultimate homework problem.)

The meaning that web search finds gives a hint, still IMO one need to become a believer to wish, not simply stop telling others one is an atheist. Maybe "in the closet" means something else here?

The author’s tone suggests that he attributes to the people he’s describing an unwillingness to be seen praying, to be caught in the act—as it were—of behaving as though they thought there might in fact be someone or something there to pray to.

The first note is that "closet" was originally a room where you went to be private.
So Matthew 6:6 was rendered in King James Version

But thou, when thou prayest, enter into thy closet, and when thou hast shut thy door, pray to thy Father who is in secret; and thy Father who seeth in secret shall reward thee openly.

A modern translation renders it

But when you pray, go to your inner room, close the door, and pray to your Father in secret. And your Father who sees in secret will repay you.

But this passage is alluding to the KJV, even though the implication is more that they are hiding their wish.
